# Why AJAX on retry sending different url request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have very stange problem: I have product list and when you click on product to edit the product you go to product form.  On this product form I have AJAX that is sending request to `getFiltersGroup`.  I want to resend this AJAX on error, but for some reason on error AJAX is start sending url request for product form not for `getFiltersGroup`.

Any ideas what is wrong, why is not sending request to `getFiltersGroup`?

This is what happen on retry:

[image]

This is the code:

```
var retry;

$('#filters-ajax').on('click', function(){

    var product_id = "<?php echo isset($set_id) ? $set_id : NULL; ?>";
    
    var ajaxConfig = $.ajax({
      url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getFiltersGroup&token=<?php echo $token ?>",
      type: "POST",
      data: '&product_id='+product_id,
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#btn-product-filter-groups').prop('disabled', true);
      },
      success: function(data){
        clearInterval(retry);
        $('#btn-product-filter-groups').prop('disabled', false);
      },
      error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
        
        retry = setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
        }, 6000)
      }
    });
})
```

**UPDATE**

I fix the url request but now I can't reset the `setInverval()`.  Also I'm never getting alert message. Any ideas what wrong?

```
var retry;

$('#filters-ajax').on('click', function(){

    var product_id = "<?php echo isset($set_id) ? $set_id : NULL; ?>";

    $.ajaxSetup({
      url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getFiltersGroup&token=<?php echo $token ?>",
      type: "POST",
      data: '&product_id='+product_id,
      dataType: 'json'
    });
    
    var ajaxConfig = $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(){
        $('#btn-product-filter-groups').prop('disabled', true);
      },
      success: function(data){
        alert('WTF')
        clearInterval(retry);
        $('#btn-product-filter-groups').prop('disabled', false);
      },
      error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
        
        retry = setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax(ajaxConfig);
        }, 6000)
      }
    });
})
```

[image]

Comment: `ajaxConfig` isn't what you think it is and I'm guessing the value of `ajaxConfig` is different in the scope before you redefine it here. Is there another variable also called `ajaxConfig` in scope before you hit `var ajaxConfig = ..,`?

Comment: @phuzi no there is only one ajaxConfig but even if i change it to something else still same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$.ajax()` returns a jqXHR object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), which you are later passing to `$.ajax()` as a configuration object for a new call:

```
var ajaxConfig = $.ajax({ ... });

// ...

$.ajax(ajaxConfig);
```

But that jqXHR object is *not* an `$.ajax()` config object, and it will not have a `url: ...` key/value pair (nor any of your other settings).  [Checking the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) for the `$.ajax()` config object it says (emphasis mine):

> jQuery.ajax( [settings ] )
> settings
> Type: PlainObject
> A set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request. **All settings are optional.**

And regarding the `url` setting:

> url (default: The current page)

So since there is no URL specified in the config object, it will default to the current page.  Your new `$.ajax()` request will request the current page, your edit page.

If you want to make your AJAX call a callable function, just put it in a function and call it:

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php?route=catalog/product/getFiltersGroup&token=<?php echo $token ?>",
        type: "POST",
        // ... your code
        error: function(xmlhttprequest, textstatus, message) {
            retry = setInterval(ajaxCall, 6000)
        }
    });
}

$('#filters-ajax').on('click', function(){
    // ...
    ajaxCall();
});
```

This approach sends off all kinds of recursive alarm bells for me though, I would consider trying another approach.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why but this one is working if anyone can explain why this code is working and previous code is not working i will accept his answer

```
        $('#filters-ajax').on('click', function(){
        var product_id = "<?php echo isset($set_id) ? $set_id : NULL; ?>";

        $('#btn-product-filter-groups').prop('disabled', true);

        $(function callAjax(){
          $.ajax(`index.php?route=catalog/product/getFiltersGroup&token=<?php echo $token ?>&product_id=${product_id}`)
          .success( function(data) {
            $('#btn-product-filter-groups').prop('disabled', true);
          })
          .error(function() {
            setTimeout ( function(){ callAjax() }, 6000);
          });
        })
      }
    })
```